# Questions About How to Save Image from BlackMagicDesign Intensity Pro Using Decklink sdk 9.7.7

Tags: emgucv

I am trying to use Decklink sdk to grab image from HDMI Input , I am using Windows 7 64bit , Visual Studio C# Express 2010 and EmguCV 2.4.0 .

My setting is

_BMDDisplayModeSupport displayModeSupport;
            IDeckLinkDisplayMode displayMode = null ;

```
        _BMDDisplayMode setDisplayMode = _BMDDisplayMode .bmdModeHD720p60;
        _BMDPixelFormat setPixelFormat = _BMDPixelFormat .bmdFormat8BitYUV;
        _BMDVideoInputFlags setInputFlag = _BMDVideoInputFlags .bmdVideoInputFlagDefault;

        _deckLinkInput.DoesSupportVideoMode(setDisplayMode, setPixelFormat, setInputFlag, out displayModeSupport, out displayMode);
        _deckLinkInput.SetScreenPreviewCallback( this );

        try
        {
            _deckLinkInput.DisableAudioInput();
            _deckLinkInput.EnableVideoInput(setDisplayMode, setPixelFormat, setInputFlag);
        }
        catch (Exception em)
        {
            Console .WriteLine("deck link init failed: " + em.Message);
        }

        _deckLinkInput.SetCallback( this );
```

And I have enabled callback function and I may see frame come to my computer

```
int frameCount = 0;
public void VideoInputFrameArrived( IDeckLinkVideoInputFrame video, IDeckLinkAudioInputPacket audio)
{
            IntPtr pData;
            video.GetBytes( out pData);
            frameCount++;
            System.Runtime.InteropServices. Marshal .ReleaseComObject(video);
}
```

Now I would like to transfer pData to a MIplimage , how may I do that ?
I guess I have to transfer the frame from YUV to RBGA , then transfer RBGA frame to MIplimage.
I saw the sample using DirectShow to solve the problem , but I am not familiar with it .
Any way to figure it out ? Thanks.